# No-Four-In-Plane, can 11 points be picked from a $4\times4\times4$ grid?

Tags: combinatorics

In the [No-Four-In-Plane problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NoFourInPlaneProblem/), points are selected so that no four of them are coplanar.

Eight points can be picked from a $3\times3\times3$ space in a unique way.

Can 11 points be picked from a $4\times4\times4$ grid so that no four points are coplanar?

What is the maximal number of points selectable from a $5\times5\times5$ grid, and beyond?

NEW

There's a [computer programming contest](http://azspcs.com/Contest/Tetrahedra) running through June 4, 2016 that asks the question "What's the most points in an *n* × *n* × *n* grid of which no 4 are coplanar?" for larger values of *n*.

Comment: There are 'only' $7\times 10^{11}$ different configurations that need to be tested, and with early-reject/branch-and-bound techniques I'd expect that to be closer to maybe $10^9$ or so.  Have you tried coding it up in C++ or the like?

Comment: Nope, I just did some random searching years ago, and noticed it as a problem I hadn't solved.

Comment: This would make a good Project Euler-style problem for an undergrad CS class, I think, but it seems really straightforward to just search: build a search tree of subconfigurations, and at each node compute the 'new' forbidden locations by filling out each plane through the most recently added point and all pairs of previous points.  (This is probably best done by iterating through all the non-forbidden points computing dot products against the cross-product; since in fact this dot product is a linear function you could also DDA it.)

Comment: Right, but this is a math site, so I assume most here are interested in knowing the structure of a general solution, and not just being able to figure out the solution.

Comment: @user99680 Many of these problems, especially their 'small-$n$' versions, seem to _have_ no general structure; for instance, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem and the associated http://oeis.org/A000769 where many of the solutions have very little structure.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki: O.K, good point, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://oeis.org/A280537 and https://oeis.org/A280538 for the 6 x 6 x 6 results.
The maximum number of points in the 6x6x6 case is 16. There are 36 solutions; a list of coordinates is provided in https://oeis.org/A280538/a280538.txt.
None of the solutions is symmetric.

Comment: So you're saying there are 36 distinct ways to pick 16 points from 6x6x6?  Could you add that so it's an answer, and give an example of such a point set?

Answer (score 8):

On $4\times 4 \times 4$:

maximal number of points for $4\times 4 \times 4$ grid is $10$.

As I checked, there are no way to build $11$ points in a $4 \times 4 \times 4$ grid (ignoring rotating, reflecting) with **No-Four-In-Plane** rule.

And there are $232$ ways to build $10$ such points:
here is this list:

```
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,3,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (2,1,2) (2,3,3) (3,1,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,3) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,1) (2,1,1) (2,3,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,1,0) (2,3,0) (3,1,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,3) (3,0,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,3) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (2,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,1,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,2) (3,1,1) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,2,1) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,3) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,2) (3,0,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,2) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,2) (1,1,2) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,2) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,1,1) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,2,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,1) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,1,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,1,3) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,2,3) (3,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,1,0) (3,1,3) (3,3,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,3,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,0,1) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,3) (2,1,3) (3,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,2,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,0,1) (3,0,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,1,3) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,1) (3,0,1) (3,2,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,1,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,1,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,3,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,1) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,1) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,1) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,1,3) (3,2,1) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,1) (3,1,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,1,1) (3,1,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,1) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,3) (3,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,2,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,1) (3,1,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,1,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,1,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,3) (3,2,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,3,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,3,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,0) (3,1,1) (3,2,1) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (1,0,0) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (2,3,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,1) (1,0,0) (1,0,1) (1,3,3) (2,2,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,1) (1,0,1) (1,1,2) (1,3,3) (2,3,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,0) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,1) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,0) (3,1,1) (3,2,1) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,2,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,1) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (3,2,0) (3,2,2) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,2,3) (2,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,2) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (3,1,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,2,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,2,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,1,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,0,1) (3,2,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (2,2,0) (3,1,0) (3,2,1) (3,3,1);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,1,0) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,3) (3,0,0) (3,1,1) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,1,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,2,0) (3,0,3) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,2) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,3) (3,1,1) (3,1,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,1,3) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,2,0) (1,2,2) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,1,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,0) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,2) (3,1,0) (3,1,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,2,0) (3,0,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,2) (3,0,3) (3,2,2) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,0,0) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,2,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,0) (3,1,0) (3,2,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,1) (3,0,0) (3,2,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (3,0,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,0,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,1) (3,1,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,3,3) (3,1,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,1) (3,2,3) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,3) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (2,2,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,2) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,1,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,2) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,1,2) (3,1,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (3,0,2) (3,3,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,2,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,1,1) (3,1,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,1) (1,2,2) (1,3,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,1,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,1) (1,3,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,1,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,1) (1,3,2) (1,3,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,2) (1,1,3) (1,3,3) (2,0,0) (3,2,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,2) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,2) (3,0,0) (3,2,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,1,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,2) (3,1,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,1) (1,0,1) (1,1,0) (1,3,3) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,2,3) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,1) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,1) (1,1,0) (1,3,2) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (3,0,2) (3,2,3) (3,3,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,0) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,2,1) (0,2,2) (1,0,0) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,3) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,3,2) (3,1,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,1) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,3) (2,3,2) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,3,0) (3,1,3) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,1) (1,2,3) (1,3,3) (2,1,2) (2,3,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,3,2) (1,1,1) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,3,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,1,1) (2,3,2) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,1,3) (1,0,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,2,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (2,3,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (2,3,3) (3,2,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,0) (2,0,1) (3,2,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,1) (2,3,2) (3,0,2) (3,1,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,2,3) (2,3,1) (3,1,1) (3,2,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (3,3,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (3,3,1) (3,3,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,1) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,2,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,0,2) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,2,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (2,2,3) (2,3,0) (3,0,1) (3,1,3);
(0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,1) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (2,1,3) (2,2,3) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,1,1) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,1,0) (2,3,2) (3,1,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,1,3) (1,0,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,3) (2,2,0) (3,1,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,2) (1,0,2) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,0) (2,1,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,2,0) (3,0,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,0) (2,1,3) (3,1,2) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,1) (1,3,0) (1,3,3) (2,1,3) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,2,0) (3,1,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,1,3) (2,2,0) (3,0,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,2) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,2) (2,3,0) (3,0,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,0) (2,3,2) (3,1,0) (3,1,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,0) (2,3,2) (3,1,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,0,2) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,2) (1,0,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,3,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,2) (2,3,1) (3,0,3) (3,2,0);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,1) (1,3,2) (1,3,3) (2,1,0) (2,3,0) (3,1,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,2) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,1) (2,1,0) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,1,0) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,0) (2,1,0) (3,0,2) (3,3,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,2,1) (1,0,0) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,3,0) (3,2,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,3) (0,3,1) (1,0,0) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,3,0) (3,2,0) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,3) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,0) (3,2,1) (3,2,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,3,2) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,1);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,3) (2,2,0) (2,3,1) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,2) (2,0,3) (2,2,0) (3,1,1) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,2,3) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (2,2,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,2) (3,1,0);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,3,1) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (2,1,1) (2,2,0) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,2,3) (2,0,1) (2,0,2) (2,3,0) (3,2,0) (3,3,2);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,0) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,1) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,2) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,3) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (2,0,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,0,2) (0,2,1) (1,2,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,3,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,2);
(0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,0) (0,0,2) (0,1,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,1,0) (2,3,1) (3,0,3) (3,2,3) (3,3,1);
(0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,1,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,2) (2,0,1) (2,3,0) (3,1,3) (3,2,3) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,3,1) (1,3,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (3,0,1) (3,2,2) (3,3,2);
(0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,3,1) (2,2,0) (2,3,3) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,3,1);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (2,0,2) (2,3,1) (3,1,0) (3,2,2) (3,2,3);
(0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,1,3) (1,3,0) (2,0,0) (2,2,3) (3,1,3) (3,2,0) (3,2,2).
```

---

On $5\times 5 \times 5$:

maximal number of points for $5\times 5 \times 5$ grid is $13$.

There are $38$ ways to build such $13$ points (ignoring rotations and reflections). Each of these ways is equivalent to certain item of this list:

```
 (0,0,0) (0,0,3) (0,3,4) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (1,4,1) (2,1,1) (3,1,4) (3,2,4) (3,4,3) (4,0,1) (4,1,2) (4,4,0); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,1,3) (1,2,4) (1,3,0) (1,4,1) (2,4,4) (3,0,2) (3,1,0) (3,3,1) (4,0,4) (4,2,3) (4,4,1); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,1,3) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (2,1,0) (2,2,4) (2,4,1) (3,0,4) (3,2,0) (4,0,2) (4,2,3) (4,4,3); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,2,1) (1,1,3) (1,1,4) (1,4,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,4) (3,2,0) (3,4,3) (4,0,2) (4,2,4) (4,3,0); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,3) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (2,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,2,4) (3,4,0) (4,0,3) (4,2,0) (4,4,2); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,1,4) (1,4,2) (1,4,4) (2,1,0) (3,0,4) (3,3,0) (3,4,1) (4,0,2) (4,2,3) (4,3,1); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,1) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (1,4,3) (2,0,4) (3,1,1) (3,2,4) (3,3,2) (4,0,3) (4,2,0) (4,4,3); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,3,2) (1,2,0) (1,3,4) (1,4,3) (2,0,1) (3,1,4) (3,2,0) (3,3,1) (4,0,3) (4,1,1) (4,2,4); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,4,1) (1,0,2) (1,1,3) (1,3,4) (2,4,0) (3,2,0) (3,3,4) (3,4,3) (4,0,3) (4,1,1) (4,3,1); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,4,3) (1,2,4) (1,3,0) (1,3,1) (2,0,4) (3,0,2) (3,3,1) (3,4,1) (4,1,0) (4,2,3) (4,4,4); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,4,4) (1,1,4) (1,4,1) (1,4,2) (2,0,1) (3,1,3) (3,2,0) (3,3,4) (4,0,3) (4,2,0) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,4,4) (1,2,4) (1,4,1) (1,4,2) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (3,1,0) (3,3,1) (4,0,4) (4,2,3) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,2) (0,4,4) (1,2,4) (1,4,3) (2,0,1) (2,1,4) (2,4,0) (3,1,0) (3,3,1) (4,2,3) (4,3,1) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,4,2) (1,0,1) (1,2,0) (1,4,4) (2,4,3) (3,0,4) (3,1,1) (3,3,4) (4,2,1) (4,3,0) (4,3,2); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,3) (0,4,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (2,0,3) (3,1,1) (3,3,4) (3,4,2) (4,1,2) (4,2,4) (4,3,0); 
 (0,0,0) (0,1,4) (0,2,3) (1,2,0) (1,3,1) (1,4,4) (2,0,0) (3,0,3) (3,3,4) (3,4,2) (4,1,2) (4,1,3) (4,3,2); 
 (0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,4) (1,4,3) (2,3,1) (3,0,4) (3,1,0) (3,1,2) (4,1,4) (4,3,1) (4,4,2); 
 (0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,3,4) (1,1,4) (1,4,2) (2,0,4) (2,1,1) (2,3,0) (3,4,1) (3,4,3) (4,0,1) (4,1,3) (4,3,0); 
 (0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,4,2) (1,1,4) (1,2,4) (1,4,0) (2,0,4) (2,1,1) (3,1,1) (3,4,3) (4,0,3) (4,3,1) (4,3,2); 
 (0,0,0) (0,2,3) (0,4,3) (1,0,0) (1,1,3) (1,4,4) (2,3,1) (3,0,4) (3,1,2) (3,4,1) (4,2,0) (4,3,2) (4,3,4); 
 (0,0,0) (0,2,4) (0,4,3) (1,2,1) (1,3,1) (2,0,3) (2,1,4) (2,4,0) (3,3,1) (3,4,4) (4,0,2) (4,1,0) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,1) (0,0,3) (0,2,0) (1,2,3) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (2,1,4) (3,1,0) (3,3,1) (3,4,4) (4,0,2) (4,1,0) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,1) (0,0,3) (0,4,2) (1,2,0) (1,3,4) (1,4,4) (2,0,1) (3,1,0) (3,3,3) (3,4,1) (4,1,3) (4,2,4) (4,3,0); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,2,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,3) (1,2,0) (2,4,4) (3,1,1) (3,3,0) (3,4,2) (4,0,2) (4,3,1) (4,3,4); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,4,0) (1,4,2) (2,1,4) (2,2,0) (3,1,0) (3,3,3) (4,0,3) (4,2,2) (4,3,1); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,3,2) (1,0,4) (1,3,3) (1,4,1) (2,3,0) (2,4,3) (3,0,0) (3,1,2) (4,2,0) (4,2,4) (4,4,3); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,1) (0,4,3) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,1,4) (2,3,0) (2,4,4) (3,2,4) (3,4,2) (4,0,1) (4,2,0) (4,3,2); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,3,3) (1,3,4) (1,4,1) (1,4,3) (2,1,0) (3,1,4) (3,2,4) (3,4,0) (4,0,2) (4,2,1) (4,3,3); 
 (0,0,1) (0,1,2) (0,4,3) (1,2,4) (1,4,1) (2,0,4) (2,3,0) (2,4,3) (3,0,0) (3,1,4) (4,1,3) (4,3,1) (4,3,2); 
 (0,0,1) (0,2,1) (1,2,0) (1,3,3) (1,4,2) (2,0,1) (2,2,4) (2,4,0) (3,0,3) (3,1,0) (4,1,3) (4,3,2) (4,3,4); 
 (0,0,1) (0,2,3) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,2,4) (1,4,2) (2,1,0) (2,4,2) (3,1,3) (3,3,0) (4,1,1) (4,3,4) (4,4,0); 
 (0,0,1) (0,2,4) (0,3,2) (1,0,3) (1,2,0) (1,4,2) (2,3,4) (2,4,0) (3,1,0) (3,1,4) (4,0,1) (4,1,3) (4,3,1); 
 (0,0,1) (0,2,4) (0,3,2) (1,1,0) (1,3,0) (1,4,4) (2,0,0) (3,1,3) (3,4,1) (3,4,2) (4,0,2) (4,2,1) (4,3,4); 
 (0,0,2) (0,3,1) (1,0,3) (1,1,0) (1,4,1) (2,0,1) (2,2,4) (2,4,0) (3,1,0) (3,4,4) (4,1,2) (4,3,2) (4,3,4); 
 (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,2) (1,2,0) (1,4,3) (2,0,0) (2,1,4) (2,4,3) (3,3,0) (3,3,1) (4,0,4) (4,1,2) (4,4,4); 
 (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,0,4) (1,3,0) (1,4,1) (2,0,1) (2,0,2) (2,4,4) (3,3,4) (3,4,3) (4,1,3) (4,2,0) (4,3,0); 
 (0,1,1) (0,2,3) (1,1,4) (1,3,3) (1,4,0) (2,0,2) (2,3,0) (2,4,1) (3,0,0) (3,0,1) (4,2,4) (4,3,4) (4,4,2); 
 (0,1,1) (0,3,3) (1,0,1) (1,2,4) (1,4,0) (2,0,3) (2,1,0) (2,2,0) (3,3,4) (3,4,3) (4,0,1) (4,3,2) (4,4,4).
```

There are no way to build $14$ points in a $5\times 5 \times 5$ grid, as I checked.

---

Easiest (than brute force search) way to find solutions is layer-by layer constructing.

Each layer need to have $1$ or $2$ or $3$ points.

So, if I need to search all $14$-points on $5\times 5 \times 5$ grid, I consider these layers configurations: 
$3:3:3:3:2$, 
$\quad 3:3:3:2:3$, 
$\quad 3:3:2:3:3$, 
$\quad \color{gray}{3:2:3:3:3}$,
$\quad \color{gray}{2:3:3:3:3}$.

To build/generate, for example, layer configuration $3:3:3:2:3$, I can add one point to 
one of $13$-points configurations: 
$\color{red}{2}:3:3:2:3$,
$\quad 3:\color{red}{2}:3:2:3$,
$\quad 3:3:\color{red}{2}:2:3$,
$\quad 3:3:3:\color{red}{1}:3$,
$\quad 3:3:3:2:\color{red}{2}$.

---

$\color{gray}{\small{\mbox{(I hope I didn't made errors in checking software)))}}}$

Comment: Nice.  I only found 211 of these 232.  I think I'll leave this open for the 5x5x5 question.